# Image with strange Padding within Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created the following code for a Homework in HTML and CSS:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-color: black;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}

td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

th {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 20px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

th {
  background-color: #656565;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.name {
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.ort {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  vertical-align: top
}

.image {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.oh {
  text-align: left;
}

.age {
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top
}

table {
  width: 70%;
}

.hl {
  border: solid red 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>People</title>
</head>

<body>

  <table align=center>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="2" class="oh">Living in</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Frank</td>
      <td class="ort">Europe</td>
      <td class="image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/70x70.jpg"></td>
      <td class="age">24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hl">
      <td class="name">Carl</td>
      <td class="ort">Canada</td>
      <td class="image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/70x70.jpg"></td>
      <td class="age">22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Fred</td>
      <td class="ort">Russia</td>
      <td class="image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/70x70.jpg"></td>
      <td class="age">17</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

The Image I'm using is 70x70px large though the Table keeps adding a ton of padding in next to it. I want the images to show up in a smaller cell with equal amounts of padding from the cell on every side. TL;DR I want the cell's width and heigth to be equal.

Note: You need to open the Snippet in fullscreen to actually see the problem, the Table needs to cover the entire page.

Placeholder Image: [© by Jeff Dean](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:70x70.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
td.image {
  width: 1%;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

**UPDATE:** (following @FluffyKitten advice)

Your problem with expanded cell with image caused by missed size specification. In this case browser balances table cell sizes automatically and on a very wide table it results into table cell size to be much larger that you want it to be (because there is no restriction for it). Setting very narrow width (1% in this case) shrinks the cell, but it still will be expandable by cell's content (image in this case).

Padding value is defined just to achieve your requested goal to have equal spacing into cell while you have `padding: 20px 5px` on `td`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'll accept the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. You should update your answer to explain what this does and how it solves the problem.  - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I've updated answer, hope it is better now